# replace parenthesis with negative sign in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do i replace entered value with '-' sign if it has parenthesis.

For example if I give ($100) or (£100) or -$100
 it should take it as -100.00
Please suggest

My entered value is

```
enteredValue = window.event.srcElement.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
var output = input.replace(/\([^\d]*([\d.]+)\)/g, '-$1')
```

input  : `"($100), (£200.3)"`

output : `"-100, -200.3"`

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/obOguce/2/)

Comment: FYI: `[^\)]` is unnecessary, a greedy `.` will match everything until the last `)`.

Comment: everything is getting replaced with -$1.If i give ($1234) its repalced with -$1 instead of -1234

Comment: No, I did in fact mean **greedy**. A greedy `.+` will match everything up until the last `)` (that's what a greedy match is, it matches `street` in `streets` using `s.+t`) - here's an [example](http://www.rexfiddle.net/0EObJ8B). With a lazy `.+?`, however, you'll get mis-matched parenthesis - [example](http://www.rexfiddle.net/Vkg3asq). I am, of course, assuming that the asker wants to include everything inside the surrounding `()`.

Comment: @SpikeX **Why** would you want to replace everything until the last ) ??? This would break (as your answer, btw) with "($100) or (£100)".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP didn't want to match that exact string, they were just listing examples, e.g. the inputs are `($100)`, `(£100)`, and `-$100`.

Answer (score 0):

You just want this expression:

```
/\((.+)\)/
```

And this replacement:

```
-$1
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://www.rexfiddle.net/fHDzRMh

---

Edit: If you don't want the currency mark:

```
/\([€$£]?(.+)\)/
```

The replacement is the same (`-$1`). Here's a fiddle: http://www.rexfiddle.net/95AcWWV

Alternately, instead of `[€$£]`, if you know the first character is always going to be a currency mark, you can just use this instead:

```
/\(.(.+)\)/
```

---

**Edit 2:** I forgot to include the `-$100` case. Here's the final expression:

```
/\(?-?[€$£]([^)]+)\)?/
```

And a fiddle: http://www.rexfiddle.net/7OBtYDk

Comment: everything is getting replaced with -$1.If i give ($1234) its repalced with -$1 instead of -1234

Comment: @SpikeX You're missing a ? to make the group not greedy. Unless you don't want to make more than one replacement.

Comment: @user3092654 Oh, you didn't want the currency mark. I've edited my post, try that instead.

Comment: /\([€$£]?(.+)\)/ worked for (100),($100) but when i give -$100,it says it is Not A Number

Comment: @user3092654 Try the last expression I just added. It handles `-$100`.

Comment: @SpikeX rexfiddle looks pretty cool. I think it's treating line endings weirdly though. In your last example, try repeating the last line twice (`-$50`). Then change `[^)]` to `[^)\n]`... /OT

Comment: it worked for -$100.but even when i give $100 it takes as -100 instead of 100 and when i give (100) it says it is Not A Number.

Comment: You can't keep changing what the requirements are. In your post you stated "**if I give ($100) or (£100) or -$100**", so that's what I gave you. If you need to modify it further, you should just learn Regex if you haven't already, and modify what I've given you (Regex isn't difficult to pick up).

Comment: @DaggNabbit It's however Javascript's implementation of Regex works, there's nothing custom beyond that (I don't do any additional parsing). I'm hoping to implement other languages, as well, it's on my todo list. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: @SpikeX, gotcha, I guess I assumed each line in that first textarea was supposed to be a distinct thing.

Comment: @DaggNabbit It is if you enable global - then it'll match as many times as you want on any of the lines. If you're using `^` and `$`, you need to set multiline on, too. For examples, that's usually how I set it up so that I can show a bunch of different cases in one fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `^[-(]\D*([\d.]+).*$`
and replace with `-$1` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dX1dW7)

if non-negative numbers are needed to be cleaned up, run this pattern `[^-\d.]` on the results and replace with nothing

Comment: worked for all the scenarios (100),-$100,($100).But dint work for $100.It says it is Not A Number

Comment: you didn't specify a non-negative no. in your post.